# run timer triggered azure function locally on MAC (inside docker)

Tags: node.js, macos, timer, azure-functions

I am trying to run a timer triggered nodejs azure function locally on MAC (inside docker) but getting the following error:

```
The listener for function 'Functions.MyTimerFunction' was unable to start. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Connection refused. System.Net.Http: Connection refused. System.Private.CoreLib: Connection refused.
```

And when I am trying to trigger the function using HTTP post I get the following error:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.DomainVerifier. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myTimer'. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Connection refused. System.Net.Http: Connection refused. System.Private.CoreLib: Connection refused.
```

this is in my `local.settings.json` file:

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce this error, I test with local windows pc. You get this error when you use `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` and  `Storage Emulator` is not start.

So set the `AzureWebJobsStorage` with your storage connection or start `Storage Emulator` on  your local environment. After start the Storage Emulator it will work .

[image]

Comment: The problem I guess is that `AzureWebJobsStorage  Emulator` is not available for MAC.

Comment: Yes for now no Storage Emulator for mac however there is open source alternative:[Azurite](https://github.com/arafato/azurite).

Comment: @mehran, if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: The Azurite moved to new place: https://github.com/azure/azurite

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround if you are using Mac and don't want to do extra setup/install extra software.

I was able to fix this issue for local development by setting the AzureWebJobsStorage in the local.settings.json to an already existing AzureWebJobsStorage Endpoint of an Azure function I had. You can find this value in the "Configuration" tab of an existing Azure function.

Or, just go ahead and publish the Azure function to Azure. It should create a AzureWebJobsStorage for you, and use this endpoint found in the configuration in Azure.